# Select AVG of a column and a single specific row

Tags: mysql

feedback table

```
-------------------------------
|rating|feedback|feedback_date|
-------------------------------
| 5    | good   | 1452638788  |
| 1    | bad    | 1452638900  |
| 0    | ugly   | 1452750303  |
| 3    | ok     | 1453903030  |
-------------------------------
```

desired result

```
average_rating | rating | feedback | feedback_date
2.25           |  3     |  ok      | 1453903030
```

Is it possible (in a single query) to select the average of one column and also one specific row from the table?

For example, i'd like to retrieve the average of the column `rating` and the most recent row as a whole.

I tried the following, and also with the `ORDER BY` direction as `DSC` but they both just gave me the `average_rating` and the first row in the table.

```
SELECT AVG(f.rating) AS average_rating, f.* FROM feedback f ORDER BY feedback_date ASC
```

Comment: mixing aggregated and non-aggregate fields isn't generally a good idea. aggregating collapses multiple records into a single record, and there's no specific guarantee as to WHICH record gets used as a source for the non-aggregated fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM feedback NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT AVG(rating), MAX(feedback_date) feedback_date FROM feedback
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e709d/1/0).

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with a sub query like this
`SELECT AVG(f.rating) AS average_rating, t1.* FROM feedback f inner join (select * from feedback order by feedback_date asc limit 1 ) t1  on true`

Answer (score 1):

You can put a subquery in the `SELECT` clause, and calculate the average in the subquery.

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM feedback) AS avg_rating, feedback.*
FROM feedback
ORDER BY feedback_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```